# access different nodes firebase database with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm still trying to access all the nodes but when I'm writing this code I'm getting the error written below. I would like to print "yes" for golf if this sport is in my database.

Everything works before the line `let dict = snap.value as! [String: any]`. ie I can write the different snaps, but then it crashes.

All the elements in my database are strings, even the coordinates. You can find a picture of my database with the link below.

```
@IBAction func testbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
       for child in snapshot.children {
        print(child)
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            print(snap)
            let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
            let msg = dict["golf"] as! String
            print(msg)
```

Error:

```
___________________________________________________
Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' 
(0x7fff87a91958) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fff87a91c78).
2020-07-21 13:18:24.131870+0200 Joiny[43447:2152693] 
Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' 
(0x7fff87a91958) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fff87a91c78).
_______________________________________________________
```

Picture of my database ->
[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in  
  let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
  let res = dict["golf"] as! [String: Any]
  let msg = res["golf"] as! String
  print(msg)
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I have another error message now:
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Users/guillaumebellanger/Desktop/Joiny post map copie 3/Joiny/RubriqueViewController.swift, line 201
2020-07-21 15:03:45.694101+0200 Joiny[44290:2207028]